# Change the Blank Icon in App Store connect

Tags: ios, app-store

I am trying to change the icon of app in App Store connect but I don't where to change , I have searched all the places , but I don't know where to update this blank icon .Please see the attached image for the reference .[image] . While I was adding the app in App Store connect ,I didnt give the icon .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once your app is released, the icon from your released build will be used.

You don't need to explicitly upload an icon to App Store Connect.

Comment: If I sent notification , which icon I will get in notification bar ?

Comment: The icon from your asset catalog in the app bundle.